# Programmatically turn off display when hold against the ear

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently developing a VoIP app. Is there a way to programmatically control the sensors to turn off the display when I hold it against my ear?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turn on proximity monitoring:

```
UIDevice.current.isProximityMonitoringEnabled = true
```

The OS will automatically blank the screen for you. If you also want to perform some other operation, you can KVO observe `proximityState` or observe the `UIDeviceProximityStateDidChange` notification.